# Measure effective CPU utilization of MySQL on Windows

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, windows-server-2016, performance-monitor

We've currently got MySQL 5.7 running on an AWS Windows 2016 Server instance, but are looking at trying it out on Amazon RDS. Before switching it over, we wanted to see what the normal & max CPU utilization was on our current instance, to help us decide what the minimum RDS instance type would be to match our needs.

I've set up performance monitor to track the "Processor Time" of "mysqld.exe", roughly following [this article](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019S9cSAE/) and [this thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/221403-how-to-get-history-report-of-the-cpu-memory-usage-on-windows-2008-r2-64-bit); however, are there other processes I should take into account / track when making this decision? Presumably ignoring things like MySQL Shell/Workbench.

Comment: Incidentally, I've just stopped the User Defined Collector Set in Performance Monitor- Was tracking MySQL's "Processor Time" alongside the default "_Total", and noticed MySQL could at points be greater than the total utilization. I assume this is because of the number of virtual CPUs on that instance (in this case 4), is this correct?

Comment: One of the best features of RDS is that you can resize instances on the fly, so whatever you choose, start conservatively and save money.  I think your assumptions about CPU utilizations may be a little off -- a server running on an EC2 instance (what type, size, e.g. m4.xlarge) is not directly comparable to a MySQL RDS instance of the similar type.  You can get a sense of all the core metrics by looking on the service page (EC2 or RDS) and clicking the monitoring tab -- this is a view into CloudWatch, which you can also look at.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that Tom. We actually did end up trying out one of the smaller instances, and we'll keep an eye on performance from there, and scale up if needs be. The server MySQL is currently sitting on is a t2.large, but it's running amongst other, somewhat intensive processes-- so we just wanted an idea about the CPU time it was currently using on its own.

Comment: Cloudwatch is your friend, then!